# How to use wp_editor(); in functions.php then retrieve content in the template

Tags: posts, functions, content, wysiwyg, wp-editor

I want to use wp_editor(); (custom editor)

I've tried several methods but I am lost and I can't get it to save the post and retrieve the content in template

[How to edit posts with the new wp_editor api?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30940/how-to-edit-posts-with-the-new-wp-editor-api)

also

```
add_action( 'edit_page_form', 'my_second_editor' );
function my_second_editor() {
    // get and set $content somehow...
    wp_editor( $content, 'my_second_editor' );
}
```

Looking for a simple solution which allow me to post the content and display in a same manner as the_content(); would with default editor...

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a metabox and then add the wp_editor as a field.  You'll then need to process/save the meta data before you ever get to the part where display the data.

I just did this this morning with the [Types plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types), which is about the easiest thing that I've found. ([Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) and [Metabox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/meta-box/) are also good options)

Or to code your metabox from scratch you could use the code from this answer: [Post custom metabox textarea using wp_editor](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49901/post-custom-metabox-textarea-using-wp-editor#answer-49906)

The trick I use to format it properly on the output is adding the following to function.php:

```
/*
 * Recreate the default filters on the_content
 * this will make it much easier to output the meta content with proper/expected formatting
*/
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wptexturize' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_smilies' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'convert_chars' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'meta_content', 'prepend_attachment' );
```

Then where ever you need to display the meta content call

```
if( $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ID-of-your-meta-field', true ) ) : 
    echo apply_filters('meta_content', $meta );
```

Comment: I've read that method is buggy?

Comment: Which method are you referring to?

Comment: Metabox with WYSIWYG editor?

Comment: It is only buggy in that you can't drag the metabox around because TinyMCE will break until you refresh the page.  Otherwise it works just fine.

Comment: @MonteCristo Did you get a chance to try this?